# CSS Select first non-th containing tr

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

Say I have a table like this:

[image]

(The red rows are `<th>`'s)

**In CSS, I would like to select the first row that is not a header row.**

```
.tableClass td:first-child {}
```

Selects `td 3:1` and `td 4:1`.

But when I try:

```
.tableClass td:first-child tr:first-child {}
```

Nothing gets selected.

What am I missing here?

Note: Rows will not contain `<td>` and `<th>` elements, just one type per row.

Comment: `td` is for selecting column, you have to use `tr` instead

Comment: do you know how many th's there are in advance? if not - then i don't think you can do this with CSS

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do it in pure CSS.  Do you have any control over the HTML?  If the header rows always come first (as in your diagram) then putting the header rows inside a `<thead>` and the other rows inside a `<tbody>` will then allow you to select the first `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>` with

```
.tableClass tbody tr:first-child {}
```

Your

```
.tableClass td:first-child tr:first-child {}
```

is selecting the first row which is inside each first-child cell which is why it is not finding anything.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the table structure is like this

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>....</th>...</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>..</td>....</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

so it is easy to find the body part of a table

```
.tableClass tbody{
//code
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: `.tableClass tr:first-child td:first-child {}`? You should always go from top to bottom when selecting an element through CSS (so *table -> table row -> table cell*).

Comment: That won't find aything in this case, since the first-child row does not contain a td, just th.  Quite right about the top-to-bottom selection though